# RowFilter.regexFilter multiple columns

Tags: java, regex, jtable, rowfilter

I am currently using the following to filter my `JTable`

```
RowFilter.regexFilter( 
         Pattern.compile(textField.getText(), 
         Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).toString(),     columns );
```

How do I format my `textField` or filter so if I want to filter multiple columns I can do that. Right now I can filter multiple columns but my filter can only be of one of the columns

An example might help my explanation better:

```
Name Grade GPA
Zac   A    4.0
Zac   F    1.0
Mike  A    4.0
Dan   C    2.0
```

The text field would contain `Zac A` or something similar and it would show the first Zac row if `columns` was `int[]{0, 1}`. Right now if I do the above I get nothing. The filter `Zac` works but I get both `Zac`'s. `A` also works but I would then get `Zac A 4.0` and `Mike A 3.0`.

I hope I have explained my problem well. Please let me know if you do not understand.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Looks like you either need to create a separate filter for each column and combine them with an [AndFilter](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#andFilter%28java.lang.Iterable%29), or write your own filter by overriding the [include()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/RowFilter.html#include%28javax.swing.RowFilter.Entry%29) method.  A RegexFilter only requires one of the specified columns to match, and there doesn't seem to be a way to change that.

By the way, if you want to force the regex to ignore case, you should add `(?i)` to the beginning of it.  The string you're generating is the same as the one you started with, despite your use of the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag.

EDIT: The doc I linked to contains an example of creating an AndFilter from two RegexFilters, but the example is pretty silly. It creates a filter that looks for `foo` in any column or `bar` in any column--which is exactly the same as a single RegexFilter with `foo|bar` as the regex and no columns specified.  A good AndFilter example should do something only an AndFilter can do: enforce conditions on two or more columns at once, like you're trying to do.  Here's how I would filter case-insensitively for `Zac` in the first column and `A` in the second:

```
List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> rfs = 
    new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>(2);
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)^Zac$", 0));
filters.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)^A$", 1));
RowFilter<Object,Object> af = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);
```

Also, if I were accepting the filter text as user input (which you seem to be doing), I would probably quote it first:

```
String regex = "(?i)^" + Pattern.quote(input) + "$";
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you can add an AndFilter to another AndFilter correct?

Also, where do I add the `(?i)`? Everywhere I have put it, I get an error.

Comment: An AndFilter ISA RowFilter, so I don't see why you couldn't add one to another, but I don't see a need to do that here.  See my edit, which covers the `(?i)` as well.

Comment: I got the insensitive case to work. I did not include the `^` or `$` though, just the `(?i)` - it didn't work otherwise. Working on making the `AndFilter` now.

Comment: I created the `AndFilter`. It appears to work perfectly. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 9):

By combining the oracle's tutorial on [tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) and the answer from [Alan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2496855/284263), I made this:

```
RowFilter<PublicationTableModel, Object> rf = null;
List<RowFilter<Object,Object>> rfs = 
            new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object,Object>>();

try {
    String text = txtFilter.getText();
    String[] textArray = text.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < textArray.length; i++) {
        rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + textArray[i], 0, 1, 2, 4));
    }

    rf = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);

} catch (java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException e) {
        return;
}

sorter.setRowFilter(rf);
```

It's a pretty simple filter that takes all the text from a textbox, splits the words and dynamically creates many filters. Then, combining them with an andFilter and putting in back to the sorter for the table model.

Answer (score 2):

```
RowFilter<TableModel, Object> filter =
    RowFilter.orFilter(Arrays.asList(RowFilter.regexFilter(lookup,0),
    RowFilter.regexFilter(lookup, 1)));
```

or

```
RowFilter<TableModel, Object> filter =
    RowFilter.regexFilter(Pattern.compile(lookup,Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE).toString(),0,1);
```

0 and 1 are the column numbers